# Vuejs nested JSON response

Tags: json, vue.js

Here goes:

I can access a vue model value, created from a ajax request in a loop like this:

```
{{ post.id}}
```

But i cant access this:

```
{{ post.featuredImageUrl.id}}
```

.

```
<div id="frontpage">
    <div id="app" class="container">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="post in posts">
            <div v:if="post.featured_media">
                    <!—-do not work—>               
                    <p>{{post.featuredImageUrl.id}}</p>
                    <!—-works—>             
                <p>{{post.id}}</p>
            </div>
            <div v:if="!post.featured_media"><p>no image</p></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

//JS

```
var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',          
      data: {
        siteUrl:'http://localhost:3000/',
        posts:[]
      },
      created: function () {
        this.listFiles();
      },


      methods: {

        listFiles: function() {

          var myUrl = "/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
          var self = this
          xhr.open('GET', myUrl)
          xhr.onload = function () {
            self.posts = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          }
          xhr.send()
        }
      }

    });
```

This is the json from one post:

```
{
"id":176,
"date":"2016-12-14T23:56:09",
"date_gmt":"2016-12-14T22:56:09",
"guid":{
    "rendered":"http://site.dev/2016/12/14/qui-harum-consequatur-veritatis/"
},
"modified":"2016-12-14T23:56:09",
"modified_gmt":"2016-12-14T22:56:09",
"slug":"qui-harum-consequatur-veritatis",
"type":"post",
"link":"http://site.dev/2016/12/14/qui-harum-consequatur-veritatis/",
"title":{
    "rendered":"Qui harum consequatur veritatis"
},
"content":{
    "rendered":"<p>Quae alias repellendus dolores cupiditate repellat ad. Error voluptatem soluta voluptatem labore repellat. Quos in quia eveniet.</p>\n<p>Repellendus iure voluptatibus aut sit sunt et id. Quia consequatur sed consequatur eum blanditiis nihil natus. Sapiente ut ut qui voluptatem quod recusandae ut. Minus aut enim et quod.</p>\n<p>Harum est unde dicta ad. Eius quia vero aut. Aliquid tempore perspiciatis repellat ratione itaque repudiandae beatae. In et ut perspiciatis.</p>\n<p>Veniam voluptatibus velit recusandae quas. Non eveniet tenetur adipisci assumenda quia. Aut eos optio alias.</p>\n<p>Et ratione eum iure hic ipsam. Dolorem suscipit delectus nisi id sed non in. Voluptatem eos molestiae numquam beatae reiciendis eaque labore.</p>\n",
    "protected":false
},
"excerpt":{
    "rendered":"<p>Quae alias repellendus dolores cupiditate repellat ad. Error voluptatem soluta voluptatem labore repellat. Quos in quia eveniet. Repellendus iure voluptatibus aut sit sunt et id. Quia consequatur sed consequatur eum blanditiis nihil natus. Sapiente ut ut qui voluptatem quod recusandae ut. Minus aut enim et quod. Harum est unde dicta ad. Eius quia vero aut. &hellip; <a href=\"http://site.dev/2016/12/14/qui-harum-consequatur-veritatis/\">Continued</a></p>\n",
    "protected":false
},
"author":1,
"featured_media":177,
"comment_status":"open",
"ping_status":"open",
"sticky":false,
"template":"",
"format":"standard",
"meta":[

],
"categories":[
    1
],
"tags":[

],
"featuredImageUrl":{
    "id":177,
    "alt_text":"",
    "caption":"",
    "description":"",
    "media_type":"image",
    "media_details":{
        "width":1263,
        "height":842,
        "file":"2016/12/d63dd99a-1c39-32e1-935e-4fb32352ddba.jpg",
        "sizes":{
            "thumbnail":{
                "file":"d63dd99a-1c39-32e1-935e-4fb32352ddba-150x150.jpg",
                "width":150,
                "height":150,
                "mime-type":"image/jpeg",
                "source_url":"http://site.dev/app/uploads/2016/12/d63dd99a-1c39-32e1-935e-4fb32352ddba-150x150.jpg"
            },
            "medium":{
                "file":"d63dd99a-1c39-32e1-935e-4fb32352ddba-300x200.jpg",
                "width":300,
                "height":200,
                "mime-type":"image/jpeg",
                "source_url":"http://site.dev/app/uploads/2016/12/d63dd99a-1c39-32e1-935e-4fb32352ddba-300x200.jpg"
            },
            "medium_large":{
                "file":"d63dd99a-1c39-32e1-935e-4fb32352ddba-768x512.jpg",
                "width":768,
                "height":512,
                "mime-type":"image/jpeg",
                "source_url":"http://site.dev/app/uploads/2016/12/d63dd99a-1c39-32e1-935e-4fb32352ddba-768x512.jpg"
            },
            "large":{
                "file":"d63dd99a-1c39-32e1-935e-4fb32352ddba-1024x683.jpg",
                "width":1024,
                "height":683,
                "mime-type":"image/jpeg",
                "source_url":"http://site.dev/app/uploads/2016/12/d63dd99a-1c39-32e1-935e-4fb32352ddba-1024x683.jpg"
            },
            "custom-thumbnail":{
                "file":"d63dd99a-1c39-32e1-935e-4fb32352ddba-220x147.jpg",
                "width":220,
                "height":147,
                "mime-type":"image/jpeg",
                "source_url":"http://site.dev/app/uploads/2016/12/d63dd99a-1c39-32e1-935e-4fb32352ddba-220x147.jpg"
            },
            "custom-thumbnail-hd":{
                "file":"d63dd99a-1c39-32e1-935e-4fb32352ddba-270x180.jpg",
                "width":270,
                "height":180,
                "mime-type":"image/jpeg",
                "source_url":"http://site.dev/app/uploads/2016/12/d63dd99a-1c39-32e1-935e-4fb32352ddba-270x180.jpg"
            },
            "custom-thumbnail-wide":{
                "file":"d63dd99a-1c39-32e1-935e-4fb32352ddba-444x296.jpg",
                "width":444,
                "height":296,
                "mime-type":"image/jpeg",
                "source_url":"http://site.dev/app/uploads/2016/12/d63dd99a-1c39-32e1-935e-4fb32352ddba-444x296.jpg"
            }
        },
        "image_meta":{
            "aperture":"0",
            "credit":"",
            "camera":"",
            "caption":"",
            "created_timestamp":"0",
            "copyright":"",
            "focal_length":"0",
            "iso":"0",
            "shutter_speed":"0",
            "title":"",
            "orientation":"0",
            "keywords":[

            ]
        }
    },
    "post":176,
    "source_url":"http://site.dev/app/uploads/2016/12/d63dd99a-1c39-32e1-935e-4fb32352ddba.jpg"
},
"_links":{
    "self":[
        {
            "href":"http://site.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/176"
        }
    ],
    "collection":[
        {
            "href":"http://site.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"
        }
    ],
    "about":[
        {
            "href":"http://site.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/types/post"
        }
    ],
    "author":[
        {
            "embeddable":true,
            "href":"http://site.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1"
        }
    ],
    "replies":[
        {
            "embeddable":true,
            "href":"http://site.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=176"
        }
    ],
    "version-history":[
        {
            "href":"http://site.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/176/revisions"
        }
    ],
    "wp:featuredmedia":[
        {
            "embeddable":true,
            "href":"http://site.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/media/177"
        }
    ],
    "wp:attachment":[
        {
            "href":"http://site.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=176"
        }
    ],
    "wp:term":[
        {
            "taxonomy":"category",
            "embeddable":true,
            "href":"http://site.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?post=176"
        },
        {
            "taxonomy":"post_tag",
            "embeddable":true,
            "href":"http://site.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/tags?post=176"
        }
    ],
    "curies":[
        {
            "name":"wp",
            "href":"https://api.w.org/{rel}",
            "templated":true
        }
    ]
}
}
```

How can I make these objects a part of the vue model?

Comment: I neither see `featuredImageUrl `,  `someObject` or `modelname` in the JSON you have posted.

Comment: Sorry for the mess in the initial post.

Comment: Can you add more code from your component, like data parta, method where you are calling ajax and populating posts.

Comment: @ saurabh,  It's  all there. the Ajax method 'listFiles' is triggered inside  vue's 'create' method.   Populating is done in the list element: ' <li v-for="post in posts">'

Comment: Are you getting an array of posts or a single post from that request?

Comment: Yes, it's an array of posts, I'm showing just one post here for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

It was a typo:

```
<div v:if="post.featured_media">
```

Should have been:

```
<div v-if="post.featured_media">
```